Python mysql.connector commands out of sync; you can't run this command now when executing stored proc
I am calling a function that uses a db cursor twice to retrieve data and pass it to an html file.
@app.route("/EditSubjects", methods = ["POST"])
def editSubjects():
    if session.get("userId") == None: #user is not logged in
        print("User not logged in")
        return redirect(url_for('main'))
    
    userId = session["userId"]
    systemSubjects = None
    tutorsubjectList = None

    getSubjects = 'select SubjectId, SubjectName from Subject;'
    
    mycursor.execute(getSubjects)
    systemSubjects = []
    for row in mycursor:
        systemSubjects.append(row)

    storedProc = f"call TutorSubjects ({userId})"

    mycursor.execute(storedProc)
    tutorsubjectList = []
    for row in mycursor:
        tutorsubjectList.append(row)
   
    return render_template('EditSubjects.html', tutorSubjects = tutorsubjectList, availableSubjects = systemSubjects)

Afterward I get to the EditSubjects.html file, I am clicking a button to add a new entry to the database by calling the following function:
@app.route("/AddSubject", methods = ["POST"])
def addSubject():
    if session.get("userId") == None: #user is not logged in
        print("User not logged in")
        return redirect(url_for('main'))
    
    userId = session["userId"]

    subject = request.form.get("subjectadd")

    success = 0


    args = (userId, subject, success)
    result_args = mycursor.callproc("AddUserSubject", args)
    db.commit()

    success = result_args[2]

    if success == 1:
        print("Subject added to user")

        return redirect(url_for("editSubjects"))
    
    else:
        print("Error adding subject to user")

        return redirect(url_for("editSubjects"))

When result_args = mycursor.callproc("AddUserSubject", args) gets executed, I obtain the following exception:

mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2014 (HY000): Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Can you please provide help? I feel that because the first function is calling two select statements, it is causing issues on the stored procedure from the second function.
I stopped using mycursor.fetchAll() and replaced it with a for loop to get all rows from the cursor into a list. I also tried opening and closing the cursor on every function, but I when the function addSubject() tried to open the cursor, a new exception was raised saying that the sql connection was not available.
I am expecting to run the stored procedure to insert a new row to the database after I run two select commands.

I don't think the problem is the select statement in editSubjects(). I suspect the problem is in the AddUserSubject stored procedure.

BTW, there's no difference between calling fetchall() and your loop.
